# StackExchange Redis - StringSet vs SetAdd and expiries

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

In [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis), the `STRING` operations allow for expiry to be set, e.g:

```
    Task<bool> StringSetAsync(
RedisKey key, 
RedisValue value, 
TimeSpan? expiry = null, 
When when = When.Always, 
CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Why is it that the `SET` operation does not?

```
    Task<long> SetAddAsync(
RedisKey key, 
RedisValue[] values, 
CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Basically, here's what i want to achieve:

Given a `List<T>`, add items to a Redis Set (either create, or add to existing) with an expiry of 1 hour.

How do i do it? Or should i be serializing the `List<T>` then use `StringSet`?

I want to use SET functions like `SREM` and add single items to the existing SET (instead of rewriting the entire SET), which is why i'm trying not to use `STRING`.

Any advice?

Comment: @marcgravell are you out there? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the first question (why do string operations have optional expirations when the set operations do not): that is simply *because that is what the redis operations expose*: `SET` (in particular with the `EX` and `PX` modifiers) and `SETEX` are the *string* operations here that allow expiration to be set. The *set* operation `SADD` exposes no such parameter. One part of this is probably to avoid confusion that the expiration would apply to the element, when in fact the expiration would apply to the entire key (i.e. the entire *set*).

Your best bet, then, is to set the expiration explicitly; at the redis level, this is via `EXPIRE`, `EXPIREAT`, `PEXPIRE` or `PEXPIREAT`; or on `IDatabase` in SE.Redis: `KeyExpire` or `KeyExpireAsync`. This must be done *after* the *set* exists; if the set is large and you are sending multiple batches and want to ensure the timeout is set even if it chokes near the end, you might want to sent the expiration after the first batch.

Comment: so I guess it's not possible to set expiry for the individual members then?

Comment: @asgs inside a set / hash / sorted set? No, not unless you encode that as part of the item manually, and check for it - perhaps also automatically sending a "remove" if you discover it to be expired at runtime.